# How to move the date above the subject in letteracdp

Tags: positioning, letters

I'm writing a letter with the `letteracdp` class, which provides nearly exactly the format I need, but I have a problem: I need to have the date and place line above the subject. How can I move it where I need it?

To be a bit more clear, this is what I need to do (please ignore the Italian formats for the subject and the date):
[image: moving the date above the subject]

---

### Update

MWE:

```
\documentclass{letteracdp}

\address{Foo Street, 1}
\signature{John Doe}

\place{Rome}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Random Road, 3}
                  [the subject]

        \opening{Dear Numerio,}

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

        \closing{Sincerely,}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for the letter, so we can play with it?

Comment: @egreg Just added the MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way.

```latex
\documentclass{letteracdp}

\address{Foo Street, 1}
\signature{John Doe}
\place{Rome}

\renewcommand*\makenormalpresentation{%
  \begin{normalpresentation}%
    \makesender\relax
    \makeaddressee\relax
%    \makesubject\relax % <---- removed
  \end{normalpresentation}%
}
\renewcommand*\OpeningSequence[1]{%
  \makepresentation
  \maketopdate[#1]%
  \vspace{2\medskipamount}%
  \makesubject % <---- added here
  \ChosenMakeOpening
}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Random Road, 3}
              [the subject]

\opening{Dear Numerio,}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]